# How do I combine link and number in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, join, concatenation, string-formatting, textjoin

Current Formula:

`=A1+TEXT(G1,0)`

A1 link example:

`https://fakesite.com/user/`

G1 Number Example:

`1`

I want to result to be

`https://fakesite.com/user/1`

This is so that I can gather API data from a website I work for, allowing me to compile user data via JSON files attached to their account. We use this information for moderation, ensuring that users are complying with rules and keeping track of our warnings and similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try just simple:

```
=A1&G1
```

...